# Confusion Matrix colors match data size and not classification accuracy

Tags: python, matplotlib, scikit-learn, confusion-matrix

I am using ConfusionMatrixDisplay from sklearn library to plot a confusion matrix on two lists I have and while the results are all correct, there is a detail that bothers me. The color's density in the confusion matrix seem to match the number of instances rather than the accuracy of the classification.

This is the code I am using to plot the confusion matrix:

```
target_names = ['Empty', 'Human', 'Dog', 'Dog&Human']
labels_names = [0,1,2,3] 
print(classification_report(y_true, y_pred,labels=labels_names, target_names=target_names))    
cm = confusion_matrix(y_true, y_pred,labels=labels_names)
disp = ConfusionMatrixDisplay(confusion_matrix=cm,display_labels=target_names)
disp = disp.plot(cmap=plt.cm.Blues,values_format='g')
plt.show()
```

Now the results I get from both the report and the confusion matrix are:

[image]

As you can see, both the classes "Dog" and "Dog&Human" achieved a precision 1, but the color of the class "Dog" is the only one with a dense blue. Even the class "Empty" which has some mis-classified instances has a darker color making it seem like the classification was better. This is obviously due to the number of data in each class, but then, shouldn't the color depend on the performance of classification and not the number of instances correctly detected ?

I tried normalizing the confusion matrix and it solves the issue, but then I would prefer having a matrix that shows the actual number and not a percentage. Is there any solution for this? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 5):

`confusion_matrix` function allows you to normalize the matrix either by row or column, which helps in dealing with the class-imbalance problem you are facing. Instead of:

```
confusion_matrix(y_true, y_pred,labels=labels_names)
```

Simply pass:

```
confusion_matrix(y_true, y_pred,labels=labels_names,normalize='true')
```

... to normalize by rows, which I think is what you want. `normalize='pred'` will allow you to normalize by columns. Check [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.confusion_matrix.html#sklearn.metrics.confusion_matrix) for further details.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I had tried `normalize='true'` before but the results were a little off, but changing it to `normalize='pred'` as you suggested, the color issue and the percentage were correct. But, is there a way to solve the color issue without having to normalize? I would like to keep the actual number of data since it gives a better understanding of the situation.